# How do you make a js movement script repeatable?

Tags: javascript

I have made the following script:

```
var object = document.getElementById("object");
        var omhoog = document.getElementById("omhoog");
        var omlaag = document.getElementById("omlaag");
        var links = document.getElementById("links");
        var rechts = document.getElementById("rechts");
        var currentInterval;

        object.style.left = '0px';
        object.style.top = '0px';

        omhoog.onclick = function()
        {
            var aantalpixels = prompt("Geef het aantal pixels in dat je het object wilt laten verplaatsen.");
            clearInterval(currentInterval);
            var positiehuidigtop = parseInt(object.style.top);
            currentInterval = setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.top)>positiehuidigtop-aantalpixels)
                {
                    object.style.top = (parseInt(object.style.top) - 1) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }

        omlaag.onclick = function()
        {
            var aantalpixels = prompt("Geef het aantal pixels in dat je het object wilt laten verplaatsen.");
            clearInterval(currentInterval);
            var positiehuidigtop = parseInt(object.style.top);
            currentInterval = setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.top)<positiehuidigtop+aantalpixels)
                {
                    object.style.top = (parseInt(object.style.top) + 1) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }

        links.onclick = function()
        {
            var aantalpixels = prompt("Geef het aantal pixels in dat je het object wilt laten verplaatsen.");
            clearInterval(currentInterval);
            var positiehuidigleft = parseInt(object.style.left);
            currentInterval = setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.left)>positiehuidigleft-aantalpixels)
                {
                    object.style.left = (parseInt(object.style.left) - 1) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }

        rechts.onclick = function()
        {
            var aantalpixels = prompt("Geef het aantal pixels in dat je het object wilt laten verplaatsen.");
            clearInterval(currentInterval);
            var positiehuidigleft = parseInt(object.style.left);
            currentInterval = setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.left)<positiehuidigleft+aantalpixels)
                {
                    object.style.left = (parseInt(object.style.left) + 1) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }
```

When i click a div, it moves another div with the amount of pixels the variable 'aantalpixels' holds at that moment. (the variables have dutch names).

It works the first time, but the second time the div goes on forever. I think it has something to do with the if statement.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail or can you make a fiddle link

Comment: ill post my full script

Comment: Try to `console.log(object.style.top, positiehuidigtop, aantalpixels)` and see the actual values. Also add `console.log("something")` markers to your code to see what's being executed and what's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't calculate the target correctly. If you move the div say 100px to the right, on the first run `positiehuidigleft+aantalpixels` will be `0100` which still is treated like 100. On the second run however `positiehuidigleft+aantalpixels` will be `0100100` which is a bit too high and thus creates the seemingly endless animation.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kLjgtm1f/)** for a working example (note: the move buttons are set absolutely 300px from top, so make sure the preview frame is large enough to see them).

The if construct was changed to

```
if (parseInt(object.style.top)>parseInt(positiehuidigtop)-parseInt(aantalpixels))
```